# Kotlin: Checking network status using ConnectivityManager returns null if network disconnected. How come?

Tags: android, kotlin, connectivity

I try to check the status of my network (connected or disconnected) using this function:

```
// Check Network status
private fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
    return if (connectivityManager is ConnectivityManager) {
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        networkInfo.isConnected
    }
    else false
}
```

This gives me a 
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: networkInfo must not be null - error**
when run with a disconnected network. Why? And how can I solve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()) `activeNetworkInfo` might be null:

> Returns details about the currently active default data network. When
>   connected, this network is the default route for outgoing connections.
>   You should always check isConnected() before initiating network
>   traffic. This may return null when there is no default network.

To make sure it doesn't crash, just use this:

```
 private fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
        return if (connectivityManager is ConnectivityManager) {
            val networkInfo: NetworkInfo? = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            networkInfo?.isConnected ?: false
        } else false
    }
```

Comment: I incorrectly assumed that **.isConnected** would always return a Boolean.

Comment: networkInfo is deprecated. Check this for an update response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532406/activenetworkinfo-type-is-deprecated-in-api-level-28

Answer (score 6):

`getActiveNetwork` has been deprecated in API 29, so this is the best solution:

```
fun isInternetAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    var result = false
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val actNw =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(networkCapabilities) ?: return false
        result = when {
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
            else -> false
        }
    } else {
        connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
            result = when (type) {
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI -> true
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE -> true
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET -> true
                else -> false
            }

        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code, it will surely help

---

```
fun checkConnectivity(context: Context): Boolean {

        val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

        val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
    
        if(activeNetwork?.isConnected!=null){
            return activeNetwork.isConnected
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way is, Add an extension to Context class like below,

```
val Context.isConnected: Boolean
get() {
    return (getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager)
        .activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected == true
}
```

Now you can use it in activity like,

```
 if (!isConnected) {
 // connection is not available...
 }
```

You can use this way in activity, fragment or anywhere within the context.