# Check for internet connectivity on API29

Tags: java, android

I use the following method for checking the internet connectivity:

```
public boolean isInternetConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Though, I have discovered that `NetworkInfo`, `getActiveNetworkInfo()`, and `isConnected()` are all now deprecated. I have checked several threads on SO:

[ConnectivityManager getNetworkInfo(int) deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547006/connectivitymanager-getnetworkinfoint-deprecated/53243938#53243938)

[activeNetworkInfo.type is deprecated in API level 28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532406/activenetworkinfo-type-is-deprecated-in-api-level-28)

Though, they all offer answers with deprecated methods. I have been looking around without any luck. Is there any simple way to check for internet connectivity or should I continue using my method and disregard the deprecated since it works up to API29?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [.hasTransport](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.html#hasTransport(int))

```
val networkAvailability = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork)
if(networkAvailability !=null && networkAvailability.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) && networkAvailability.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED))
{
    //has network
    if (networkAvailability.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) { //wifi
    } else if (networkAvailability.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) { //cellular
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this great solution. I really appreciate it.

Comment: there are more ways to be connected in real world

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for SDK 29: A class called `NetworkWatcher` which observes the changes of the network. It offers primitive variables such as `isWifiOn` and the option to observe network changes over time via [Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html) and [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class NetworkWatcher
@RequiresPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)
private constructor(
    application: Application
) {

    private val connectivityManager =
        application.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
                as ConnectivityManager

    // general availability of Internet over any type
    var isOnline = false
        get() {
            updateFields()
            return field
        }

    var isOverWifi = false
        get() {
            updateFields()
            return field
        }

    var isOverCellular = false
        get() {
            updateFields()
            return field
        }

    var isOverEthernet = false
        get() {
            updateFields()
            return field
        }

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: NetworkWatcher? = null

        fun getInstance(application: Application): NetworkWatcher {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = NetworkWatcher(application)
                }
                return INSTANCE!!
            }
        }
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    private fun updateFields() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            val networkAvailability =
                connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)

            if (networkAvailability != null &&
                networkAvailability.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) &&
                networkAvailability.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)
            ) {
                //has network
                isOnline = true

                // wifi
                isOverWifi =
                    networkAvailability.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)

                // cellular
                isOverCellular =
                    networkAvailability.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)

                // ethernet
                isOverEthernet =
                    networkAvailability.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)
            } else {
                isOnline = false
                isOverWifi = false
                isOverCellular = false
                isOverEthernet = false
            }
        } else {

            val info = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            if (info != null && info.isConnected) {
                isOnline = true

                val wifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                isOverWifi = wifi != null && wifi.isConnected

                val cellular = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                isOverCellular = cellular != null && cellular.isConnected

                val ethernet = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET)
                isOverEthernet = ethernet != null && ethernet.isConnected

            } else {
                isOnline = false
                isOverWifi = false
                isOverCellular = false
                isOverEthernet = false
            }
        }
    }

    fun watchNetwork(): Flow<Boolean> = watchWifi()
        .combine(watchCellular()) { wifi, cellular -> wifi || cellular }
        .combine(watchEthernet()) { wifiAndCellular, ethernet -> wifiAndCellular || ethernet }

    fun watchNetworkAsLiveData(): LiveData<Boolean> = watchNetwork().asLiveData()

    fun watchWifi(): Flow<Boolean> = callbackFlowForType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)

    fun watchWifiAsLiveData() = watchWifi().asLiveData()

    fun watchCellular(): Flow<Boolean> = callbackFlowForType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)

    fun watchCellularAsLiveData() = watchCellular().asLiveData()

    fun watchEthernet(): Flow<Boolean> = callbackFlowForType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)

    fun watchEthernetAsLiveData() = watchEthernet().asLiveData()

    private fun callbackFlowForType(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 7) type: Int) = callbackFlow {

        offer(false)

        val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(type)
            .build()

        val callback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
                offer(false)
            }

            override fun onUnavailable() {
                offer(false)
            }

            override fun onLosing(network: Network?, maxMsToLive: Int) {
                // do nothing
            }

            override fun onAvailable(network: Network?) {
                offer(true)
            }
        }

        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, callback)

        awaitClose { connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(callback) }
    }
}
```

For instance, you could subscribe to updates about the network state of the phone in your Application such as:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    NetworkWatcher.getInstance(this@MyApplication).watchNetwork().collect { connected ->
        Log.d("TAG", "Network In App: $connected")
    }
}
```

Or to answer your question, simply read the Wifi value such as:

```
if (NetworkWatcher.getInstance(this@BaseApp).isOverWifi) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Side note: Rather than using `getInstance()` all the time, I use a DI framework such as [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/) to inject the NetworkWatcher where I need it.

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidManifest.xml add :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

now for checking network status :

```
 @IntRange(from = 0, to = 3)
fun getConnectionType(context: Context): Int {
    var result = 0 // Returns connection type. 0: none; 1: mobile data; 2: wifi
    val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        val capabilities =
            cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                result = 2
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                result = 1
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)) {
                result = 3
            }

        }
    } else {

        val activeNetwork = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        if (activeNetwork != null) {
            // connected to the internet
            if (activeNetwork.type === ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                result = 2
            } else if (activeNetwork.type === ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                result = 1
            } else if (activeNetwork.type === ConnectivityManager.TYPE_VPN) {
                result = 3
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer which is clean and in Kotlin and also handles different API levels

```kotlin
fun isOnline(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            ContextCompat.getSystemService(DreamPad.appContext, ConnectivityManager::class.java)
        connectivityManager ?: return false
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val nw = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
            val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw) ?: return false
            when {
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                // for other device how are able to connect with Ethernet
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                // for check internet over Bluetooth
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH) -> true
                // for check internet over USB tethering
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_USB) -> true
                else -> false
            }
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected ?: false
        }
    }
```

Comment: what about TRANSPORT_USB? can't you pass internet over usb?

Comment: Hi @David if you can read the answer you will find that `TRANSPORT_USB` is already added as case before else

Comment: Mmmmm no? TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH is the last one.

Comment: Ohhh.. sorry.. Let me add that option.. `TRANSPORT_USB` will be applicable when tethering via USB