# Android check NetworkAvailable getState() is now deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using this code to check internet availability

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (NetworkInfo anInfo : info) {
                if (anInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this method is now deprecated

> .getState()

I am targeting Sdk Version 28 . Is there any alternative method I can use ?

Comment: Have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53532456/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod yes I have but the issue is different ...

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = null;
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
    }
```

You can use `NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI` and `NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR`to distinguish between cellular and wifi connection.

Comment: I didn't get the return line . It doesnt matter if customer is using wifi or cellular I just want to check if connection is available or not

Comment: also NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR requires api 21