# Import deprecated warning after updating target sdk to 29

Tags: java, android, deprecated

After updating compile and `targetSdkVersion` to "29" in `build.gradle` *I get deprecation warning:*

```
warning: [deprecation] NetworkInfo in android.net has been deprecated
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
                  ^
```

Build fails because of this. But I use Network info to have compatibility with *api versions 16-29*. How should I handle deprecated imports targeting api "29" and above?

Comment: If it's a warning then it should not fail the build.

Comment: @Kiryl Build is failing in my case also. If you resolved this issue please post a solution.

Comment: What is the older version of Android you plan to support?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this one. You must write the method in this way.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) AnkiDroidApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cm == null) {
            return false;
        }
        /* NetworkInfo is deprecated in API 29 so we have to check separately for higher API Levels */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            Network network = cm.getActiveNetwork();
            if (network == null) {
                return false;
            }
            NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
            if (networkCapabilities == null) {
                return false;
            }
            boolean isInternetSuspended = !networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_SUSPENDED);
            return networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                    && networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)
                    && !isInternetSuspended;
        } else {
            android.net.NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
        }
    }
```

Remember to suppress warning.

Answer (score -1):

The Answer of your question is in this  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57278620/4469477)!

NetworkCapabilities is not deprecated in API 29 but it requires API 21 so I have called it on API 29 only.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
if(context == null)  return false;


ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 

context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {


    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities = 

 connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if 
                (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    return true;
                } else if 
                 (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    return true;
                }  else if 
                 (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    else {

        try {
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = 
               connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
                Log.i("update_statut", "Network is available : true");
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("update_statut", "" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
    Log.i("update_statut","Network is available : FALSE ");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But I'm using the same way, the problem I'm getting warning on import line

Comment: You can ignore that warning, that won't cause any issue.