# How to detect WiFi connection/disconnection after Android 10?

Tags: android, android-wifi

Since [getNetworkInfo()](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type) is deprecated in Android 10, how can one detect WiFi connection/disconnection using [NetworkCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)? What is the proper way to obtain information about the WiFi connection?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277759/getactivenetworkinfo-is-deprecated-in-api-29 ?

Comment: I want to react to WiFi router connection or disconnection, not to check if network is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mob = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (wifi.isConnected()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "WIFI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if (mob.isConnected()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "MOBILE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "other", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```