# ActiveNetworkInfo and isConnected deprecated in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created an extension function for kotlin that detects me if I am connected to the Internet but these methods put me that they are deprecated, what methods I could use instead, I leave you the function I have:

```
    fun Context.isInternetAvailable(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager =
        this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val nw = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw) ?: return false
        return when {
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
            else -> false
        }
    } else {
        val nwInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo ?: return false
        return nwInfo.isConnected
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532406/activenetworkinfo-type-is-deprecated-in-api-level-28

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I already looked at that answer but it still contains the deprecated activeNetworkInfo method

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion that's better you use http client libraries such as `Retrofit` or `Ktor` and catch exception of network per request.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use this , its works fine in*

> kotlin

```
 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun Context.isInternetAvailable() : Boolean{

        val connectivityManager = this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
        val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork)

        return networkCapabilities!= null && networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET

    }
```