# Network State with Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to get Network State means whether the Connected network has internet connection in Jetpack Compose.
How to achieve it

Comment: Jetpack Compose generally focuses on UI concerns. Determining the state of the network is not directly related to the UI.

Comment: I think @CommonsWare makes the most sense on this question. The UI shouldn't be directly tied to something like that. Would make most sense to extract that to the VM layer, and pass in a state / boolean into the composable itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val connectivityManager 
            = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()

     Text(
if(
activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()
) "Connected"
else "Disconnected" 
)
```

This is a Composable which displays the state of the network. As correctly pointed out in the comment above, JC is focused more on the UI, so all the rest of the stuff is still the same old Android way. JC just efficiensizes(?) the GUI development

Comment: This only show about connected Wi-Fi or Cellular network but not about the active Internet connection

Comment: I don't think so. Please recheck

Comment: It show about active internet Connection? or Active Network

Comment: I think it tells about active internet connection

Comment: Actually I don't have access to My Android Studio for some days so I'm trying to clear all error or stops that's why was asking?

Comment: Confirmed from the docs as well. It tells internet connection not connection type. It is the only way to know it, that is mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Thanks Marsk for helping

Comment: Anytime, glad to help.

Answer (score 6):

If your running into trouble with the `connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo` being deprecated, try using this:

```
private fun isInternetAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    var result = false
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(networkCapabilities) ?: return false
        result = when {
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
            else -> false
        }
    } else {
        connectivityManager.run {
            connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                result = when (type) {
                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI -> true
                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE -> true
                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET -> true
                    else -> false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

I got the answer from the accepted answer of another question.
Feel free to check it out: [activeNetworkInfo is Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53532456/8279887)

When working with JC, use this to access the context:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. 
As James has pointed out, using activeNetworkInfo is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sharing my connectivity flow solution here, even though an answer has been accepted. This solution seamlessly integrates with Jetpack Compose and has been thoroughly debugged and simplified. Feel free to try and copy-paste the solution.

It combines the solution used by Google in WorkManager and `callbackFlow`.

Here are the relevant classes: `NetworkState`, which holds the current network states, and `ConnectionState`, which is important for UI components.

```
private data class NetworkState(
  /** Determines if the network is connected. */
  val isConnected: Boolean,

  /** Determines if the network is validated - has a working Internet connection. */
  val isValidated: Boolean,

  /** Determines if the network is metered. */
  val isMetered: Boolean,

  /** Determines if the network is not roaming. */
  val isNotRoaming: Boolean
)

sealed class ConnectionState {
  object Available : ConnectionState()
  object Unavailable : ConnectionState()
}
```

To compute the `NetworkState`, use the `activeNetworkState` property extension on `ConnectivityManager`.

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
private val ConnectivityManager.activeNetworkState: NetworkState
  @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
  get() {
    // Use getActiveNetworkInfo() instead of getNetworkInfo(network) because it can detect VPNs.
    val info = activeNetworkInfo
    val isConnected = info != null && info.isConnected
    val isValidated = isActiveNetworkValidated
    val isMetered = ConnectivityManagerCompat.isActiveNetworkMetered(this)
    val isNotRoaming = info != null && !info.isRoaming
    return NetworkState(isConnected, isValidated, isMetered, isNotRoaming)
  }
```

For checking if the active network is validated, use the `isActiveNetworkValidated` property extension on `ConnectivityManager`.

```
private val ConnectivityManager.isActiveNetworkValidated: Boolean
  @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi", "MissingPermission")
  get() =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
      false // NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED not available until API 23. Used on API 26+.
    } else
      try {
        val network = activeNetwork
        val capabilities = getNetworkCapabilities(network)
        (capabilities?.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)) ?: false
      } catch (exception: SecurityException) {
        Timber.tag("NetworkStateTracker").e(exception, "Unable to validate active network")
        false
      }
```

A `callbackFlow` to convert a `NetworkCallback` to a `Flow`. Everytime there is a callback method called, this function computes the `ConnectivityState` and sends it.

```
/** Network Utility to observe Internet connectivity status */
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
private fun Context.observeConnectivityAsFlow() =
  callbackFlow {
      val connectivityManager =
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

      fun sendConnectionState() =
        with(connectivityManager.activeNetworkState) {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            if (isConnected) {
              trySend(ConnectionState.Available)
            } else {
              trySend(ConnectionState.Unavailable)
            }
          } else {
            if (isConnected && isValidated) {
              trySend(ConnectionState.Available)
            } else {
              trySend(ConnectionState.Unavailable)
            }
          }
        }

      val networkRequest =
        NetworkRequest.Builder()
          .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
          .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
          .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
          .build()

      val networkCallback =
        object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
          // satisfies network capability and transport requirements requested in networkRequest
          override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(
            network: Network,
            networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities
          ) {
            sendConnectionState()
          }
          override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            sendConnectionState()
          }
        }

      connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback)

      awaitClose {
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
      }
    }
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

A publicly available method to collect the `ConnectionState`

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Composable
fun connectivityState(): State<ConnectionState> {
  val context = LocalContext.current
  return produceState<ConnectionState>(initialValue = ConnectionState.Unavailable) {
    context.observeConnectivityAsFlow().collect { value = it }
  }
}
```

And finally in your composable

```
@Composable
fun YourAwesomeComposable(
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
  val networkConnectivity by connectivityState()
  ...
  ...

  if (networkConnectivity == ConnectionState.Unavailable) {
     // Unavailable UI
  } else {
     // Available UI
  }
}
```