# Android WorkManager setRequiredNetworkType Wi-Fi vs Cellular

Tags: android, android-workmanager

New to Android development and, in using WorkManager for the first time, I’m also employing setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED) in my Constraints to make certain an Internet connection is available when my worker runs.  My issue is, when a device is not charging, its screen is off and it’s on a mobile network, an HTTP connection from my worker fails with java.net.SocketException, java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException and others more than 50% of the time.  I’ve also tried to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/61152364/1434047 with a delay, but it’s not helpful.  In contrast, with all things the same, when a device is on a Wi-Fi network or the screen is on, this is far more reliable.

Anyone else have this issue and know how to fix?

Thanks—here is my code to create the work:

```
fun setAlarm(context: Context) {
    val data = Data.Builder().putLong("id", id).build()
    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()
    val scheduleRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ProcessScheduledMessage>()
        .setInputData(data)
        .setInitialDelay(Instant.now().until(time, ChronoUnit.MINUTES), TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(context)
        .enqueueUniqueWork(id.toString(), ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, scheduleRequest)
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Retrying the connection helps a little, but the issue persists.